# Is there a way to convert this javascript code to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to convert this javascript code to jQuery?

```
document.writeln('Nu te teme, căci Eu sunt cu tine; nu te uita cu îngrijorare, căci Eu sunt Dumnezeul tău; Eu te întăresc, tot Eu îţi vin în ajutor. Eu te sprijin cu dreapta Mea biruitoare.”');
document.write('<a onclick="var w=window.open(this.href);w.focus();return false;" href="http://biblia.resursecrestine.ro/citeste/isaia/41">Isaia 41:10</a>');
```

In joomla 1.5 i was able to insert the above javascript; not anymore in joomla 1.6. This needs to be converted in jQuery somehow.

Comment: Can you explain why you'll need to convert this?

Comment: because the above listed code is not accepted in joomla 1.6 enviroment, they aonly take jquerry and i have no clue how to convert the above code in jquerry, that is why i need help converting

Comment: you do realize that jQuery *is* JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the idea is to locate where you want to put what and insert it:

$("mydiv").append("bla bla bla");

Comment: +1 But I think the answer could be slightly more refined with also considering the semantics/ramifications of document.write (which is a very ... unique ... function). In particular, it is relatively hard to locate "an arbitrary position of the document" outside of nodes / node edges (in general text, for instance). Also consider the timing (time, not speed) of insertion.

Comment: Thanks, you're right but there isn't enough data as to where/how he was using this line of javascript, so I am just pointing him to the right paradigm instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need a better understanding of the Joomla framework. I know *nothing* about it, but by simply reading the [changelist](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aMigrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_1.6), I was able to gather that Joomla doesn't (by default) incorporate jQuery, they've adopted Mootools.

Asking a question (repeatedly, and a vague one at that) with zero understanding of the actual problem will more times than not lead you in the wrong direction.

So, my advice is to do a little more research on the framework you're using and maybe some on Javascript as well. In doing so, you might also figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: I am trying to get better on jquery since the javasript code i use to work with in joomla 1.5 is not acceptablae anymore in joomla 1.6 and I THOUGHT BY POSTING THE JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE SOMEBODY WILL POINT ME TO A CONVERSION IN JQUERY

Comment: Yelling doesn't help anyone. My point is you should figure out **why** it doesn't work in Joomla 1.6 anymore. There could be a reason that has absolutely *nothing* to do with whether or not it's using jQuery. If you're simply trying to get better using jQuery, then state that in your question and not that it is a requirement of your upgrade to Joomla 1.6.

Comment: is there an equivalent fot his javascript code

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.resursecrestine.ro/web-api-versetul-zilei"></script>

to do it in jquery?

Comment: I give up. I'm starting to think that this thread is a troll.